# python3 xhr requests codeforces

Tags: python, python-requests, xmlhttprequest

Initially I did this via javascript using selemium but due to errors, I decided to rewrite to requests (then if possible to aiohttp)..

The codeforces site has its own api but there is one for getting the task analysis https://codeforces.com/data/problemTutorial it is not in the documentation (this can be seen if you go to the contest review). These requests have the form

[xhr requests from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNBQ6.png)

I tried to make a request but it doesn't work

```py
import requests
from lxml.html import HtmlElement, fromstring
from lxml import html

from lxml import html
from lxml.etree import tostring

s = requests.session()


def get_token():
    url = "https://codeforces.com/profile/MiFaFaOvO"
    html = s.get(url).text
    tree = fromstring(html)
    return tree.xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div[3]/div[5]/form/input[1]')[0].get(
        "value"
    )


csrf_token = get_token()
print(csrf_token)
url = "https://codeforces.com/data/problemTutorial"
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "X-CSRF-Token": csrf_token,
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36",
}

a = s.post(
    url,
    data={"problemCode": "1371A", "csrf_token": csrf_token,},
    headers=headers,
)
print(a.url, a, a.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution was simple

1. it was necessary to pass data={} to post
2. when getting csrftoken it was necessary to make a request with the browser header like there is a protection for this)

```py
import requests
from lxml.html import HtmlElement, fromstring
from lxml import html

from lxml import html
from lxml.etree import tostring

s = requests.session()

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36",
}


def get_token():
    url = "https://codeforces.com/profile/MiFaFaOvO"
    html = s.get(url, headers=headers).text
    tree = fromstring(html)
    return tree.xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div[3]/div[5]/form/input[1]')[0].get(
        "value"
    )


csrf_token = get_token()
headers["x-csrf-token"] = csrf_token
headers["x-requested-with"] = "XMLHttpRequest"
url = "https://codeforces.com/data/problemTutorial"


a = s.post(
    url,
    data={"problemCode": "1371A", "csrf_token": csrf_token,},
    headers=headers,
)
print(a.text)
```

aiohttp

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio

from lxml.html import fromstring
from lxml import html


headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36",
}


async def get_token(session):
    resp = await session.get("https://codeforces.com/profile/MiFaFaOvO")
    async with resp:
        html = await resp.text()
        return (
            fromstring(html)
            .xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div[3]/div[5]/form/input[1]')[0]
            .get("value")
        )


async def problemData(task, session, csrf_token):
    resp = await session.post(
        "https://codeforces.com/data/problemTutorial",
        data={"problemCode": task, "csrf_token": csrf_token,},
        headers={
            "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
            "x-csrf-token": csrf_token,
        },
    )
    async with resp:
        return (await resp.json())["html"]


async def main():
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    csrf_token = await get_token(session)
    tasks = ["1371A", "1360B", "1370A"]
    for future in asyncio.as_completed(
        [problemData(task, session, csrf_token) for task in tasks]
    ):
        res = await future
        print(res)
    await session.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```